# Run cron jobs with same cron-time on a 10s interval queue

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue

So basically I couldnt find my answer elsewhere. I'm having an issue with Laravel 5.x in where I have models called 'Bumpers' which can have a certain cron-time value (say 'every 25 minutes').

Many bumpers can have the same cron-time, meaning that at a certain time, many of these bumpers may be executed using the [Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling). However, I need to run these bumpers 10 seconds apart from eachother. So if 10 bumpers are triggered at 8:00:00PM, I need the queue to run with 10 seconds interval until all bumpers have been executed.

I've tried adding `sleep();` to the `$schedule->call(function(){executeStuff(); sleep(10)});`. That worked for a bit but unfortunately it only works for queues not exceeding 60 seconds because then the Scheduler is ran again:

```
// This function is called on "artisan schedule:run"
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // Get only the active bumpers.
    $bumpers = Bumper::where('status', 1)->get();

    // Register all bumpers through their occurrence value.
    foreach ($bumpers as $bumper) {
        // Check for member/admin. All other bumpers are neglected.
        if ($bumper->user->canBump()) {
            $schedule->call(function () use ($bumper) {
                sleep(10);
                $bumper->post();
            })->cron($bumper->occurrence);
        }
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Keep a loop and only run it 5 times?

Comment: unsure what you mean there

Comment: Maybe you need to utilize something like pcntl_fork or pthreads to fork a new process or create a new thread to handle each bumper.  You can  use pcntl_fork/pthreads in conjunction with sleep to only create/fork a new process/thread every 10s.  This way your foreach can continue processing each new bumper every 10s, without having to wait for your bumper to finish.